# Interdependence of variables within Manipulate[]

Tags: manipulate

I would like to create a Manipulate[] with several interdependent variables. E.g. consider this simple example

```
Manipulate[x = 3*y; {x, y}, {y, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 6}]
```

The problem is that Manipulate[] only lets me manipulate the variable on the RHS. However, I would like to be able to manipulate both variables.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `==` not `=`.

Comment: @zhk: using == doesn't seem to make the two variables interdependent

Comment: Is this something like what you want?  `DynamicModule[{x, y},
 Column[{
   {Dynamic[x], Dynamic[y]},
   Slider[Dynamic[y, y = #; x = 3 y; &], {0, 2}],
   Slider[Dynamic[x, x = #; y = x/3; &], {0, 6}]
   }]
 ]`  The sliders aren't as pretty as in Manipulate, but I don't know how to use the second argument of Dynamic within Manipulate.

Comment: `Manipulate[{x, y}, {y, 0, 2, 
  TrackingFunction :> ((y = #; x = 3 y) &)}, {x, 0, 6, 
  TrackingFunction :> ((x = #; y = x/3) &)}]`

Comment: awesome! this works. thank you kuba for the solution. also thanks jjc385 for a solution that works also :)

Comment: @onion I've closed it as a duplicate because it seems this is the case. Let me know if you disagree.